# Angular Universal not rendering

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

So I am adding angular universal to my angular app and my app-component has only 
`<router-outlet>` in it. But for some reason the rendered file to be served with node doesn't show anything. just keep loading. If I were to remove the `<router-outlet>` and replace it with some html say `<h1>Something</h1>`, It works prefectly.
NB: the route works perfectly if I was to "ng serve". even if I add

`<app-somecomponent></app-somecomponent>`

the rendered file doesn't work(just keeps loading).

Comment: Any error server/client side?

Comment: No errors present @David